# How to stretch container div from header to footer with html/css?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to stretch my red `content` cless to stretch from the footer to the header. I know if I fill it with content it will, but how do I make it stretch as is?

You can clone the project [here](https://github.com/eveo/Sam)

relevant code:

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="nav">
                <div class="logo">
                    <strong>
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Sam Jarvis logo"/>
                        </a>
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#work">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#clients">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footercontent">
            <p>&copy; 2013 Friend | Design and Development. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {

    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -6.25em;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.content {
    width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Add the rule `html,body {height:100%}`
2. Remove the `height: auto !important;` from `#wrapper`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9EEv/)**

Comment: Wicked thanks. That worked. Removed that and added `overflow; hidden` so I can add data and not mess with the layout of the footer and content. Did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That you are looking for is named "sticky footer" and you can check an example in this url:
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Your html must have a specific structure...

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        [YOUR CONTENT INCLUDING HEADER]
        <div class="push"></div>[this div is required]
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        [YOUR FOOTER]
    </div>
</body>
```

Remember:
If .push and .footer have height:100px; then .wrapper must have margin: 0 auto -100px.

Pay attention to every style applied because every one is important.